# What effects libraries are available for GWT for commercial use?

Tags: gwt, effects

I'm looking for an effects library that I can drop in to my existing GWT app really, really easily.  I want to add the library to my build path and then start writing things like `FX.fadeOut(thisWidget)` to replace `thisWidget.setVisible(false)`.

Is there anything solid and small available for GWT that can do this kind of simple thing?  I'm writing an app for commercial use that will not be open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fx/

Cheers

Comment: gwt-fx was the lightest weight library I could find.  It's got an acceptable amount of flexibility and the code is simple and easy to extend.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), a JQuery clone for GWT. The docs for the effects class are [here](http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gwtquery-core/javadoc/com/google/gwt/query/client/plugins/Effects.html).
It is licensed under the Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [GWT-Mosaic2g](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mosaic/wiki/GWTMosaic2g)

It's a complete new GWT-Mosaic library, with really nice animation effects.

Answer (score 0):

I needed just fade in and fade out effects. So I didn't use a library. 
This is the code doing these effects.

```
    private void fadeIn(final Element el) {
    final int size = 11;
    Timer timer = new Timer() {
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {                     
            if (counter == size) {
                cancel();
                return;
            }
            double opacity = (double) (counter) /  10;                      
            el.getStyle().setOpacity(opacity);                      
            counter++;      
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(100);   


}

private void fadeOut(final Element el) {
    final int size = 11;
    Timer timer = new Timer() {
        private int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {                     
            if (counter == size) {
                cancel();
                return;
            }
            double opacity = (double) (10 - counter) /  10;                     
            el.getStyle().setOpacity(opacity);                      
            counter++;      
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(100);       
}
```