# How to rotate a Widget in GWT?

Tags: gwt, animation, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a Widget (a LayoutPanel in fact) in GWT. I think this is possible in e.g. jQuery, but can't seem to find out how to do it in (pure) GWT. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating a `<div>` element is not that easy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery) for some input. The effects libraries for GWT I know of (some listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102956/what-effects-libraries-are-available-for-gwt-for-commercial-use)) do not provide support for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<yourwidget>.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("transform", "rotate(20deg)");
```

You can can do lots of transformations following the same pattern.